# A bunch of posts got deleted because I didn't disclose my association

Tags: support, deleted-answers

A bunch of posts got deleted because I didn't disclose my association. I seem to be banned now. How can I rectify this? My answers were very useful and meant to help. I didn't realize I needed to identify that I was the author of the OSS projects.

FYI - I edited the deleted posts to add a disclosure message. Maybe it's too late for that though.

Comment: Do you have links to the deleted posts?  (10K users and moderators can see them)

Comment: I've declined all of the flags, not the important part of the disclosure section of the FAQ: "if a huge percentage of your posts..." Right now 100% of your posts (five answers) are promotional.  Also, your answers are really just link-only answers, which aren't good answers to begin with.

Comment: That's not true. Here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394140/how-do-you-backup-zookeeper/13691704#13691704) I explain how Exhibitor does backups of ZooKeeper data. In this one (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286054/is-it-possible-to-start-a-zookeeper-server-instance-in-process-say-for-unit-tes/13691653#13691653) I explain how Curator has a test server and test cluster. In this one (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11375126/zookeeper-adding-peers-dynamically/13691582#13691582) I talk about upcoming dynamic reconfig and how you can use Exhibitor until then. The others are similar.

Comment: This one (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12438584/working-with-zookeeper/13691366#13691366) is the oddest deletion. The answer above mine mentions Curator but implies it's Java only. I posted to show that Curator works with Scala and it gets deleted.

Comment: In this one (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11675468/establishing-a-new-service-leader-and-informing-the-lead/13691534#13691534) the questioner asks "Is there an existing recipe or recipes that I should be looking at to solve this problem?". The correct answer is - "yes, use Curator". So, I posted that and it got deleted. I don't get it.

Comment: My account is still banned, BTW, which seems very unfair. I was genuinely trying to answer questions regarding Curator and ZooKeeper. How do I get un-banned? E.g. I'd love to answer this question regarding Curator but can't: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169538/answer/submit

Comment: Link above should be: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169538/path-cache-triggers-events-on-all-children-when-adding-and-deleting-one-curator

Answer (score 4):

If you still have the links to the deleted posts, you may be able to edit them and then flag for moderator attention. If not, then a moderator on MSO may be able to pull the deleted answers for you, assuming you do intend to make the necessary improvements.

Improving them and getting upvotes would lift the ban.

Additionally, the link you got with the ban should explain other techniques for lifting the ban, which is automated and can only be lifted by performing positive actions on the site, such as editing, asking well-researched questions (assuming you're only answer-banned), etc.

For instance, you can suggest edits to other posts that need improvement. If those edits are improved, that will give you rep and help undo the ban.

*If you've edited the deleted posts to add in your affiliation, you can still flag them, as long as you have a link. Or flag the question and explain the situation.*

In the future, just be careful. If your goal here is to promote a project you're working on, Stack Overflow might not be the right site for you. If an occasional post contains your product, that's fine, but if all your answers contain links to your product, you're here for the wrong reason. ;)

Please see the [FAQ section on Promoting](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) for more details:

> **May I promote products or websites I am affiliated with here?**
>
> Be careful, because the community frowns on overt self-promotion and tends to vote it down and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, so be it. However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers.
>
> If a huge percentage of your posts include a mention of your product or website, you're probably here for the wrong reasons. Our advertising rates are quite reasonable; contact our ad sales team for details. We also offer free community promotion ads for open source projects and non-profit organizations.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's a good point @Bart. If it sounds/smells like spam, the community will treat it like spam.

Comment: Thanks - I edited the posts and flagged for moderation

BTW - I wasn't trying to promote my project. People were asking questions about ZooKeeper and my projects (Curator and Exhibitor) provide solutions to those questions. It seems reasonable to suggest them as solutions.

Comment: Sorry, deleted my comment. Your edit covered it. :)

Comment: @JordanZimmerman - Certainly :)  Most spammers don't post on our meta site or edit their posts to improve them. :) That said, sometimes legitimate posts do get caught up in site moderation because they *look* like spam. Just edit your posts to make it clear how it solves the problem being asked, and always make sure to disclose your affiliation in the future and you should be fine. Good luck! :)